# Display Rows with Month and Year PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got all my archived entries to display like so,

**2015 Entries**

- March [2]
- April [10]
- November [6]

**2004 Entries**

- January [5]
- February [7]
- December [19]

Now I'm stuck and I've been trying to figure out how to display archived entries by selecting a specific month and year. Let's say I wanted to view on my all entries during November 2015, then my link on the address bar would look something like...

**display.php?year=2015&monthname=November**

When I executed the code, the entries shows up as blank. So far, my code looks like this. I also used the type **datetime** as my *date* field. Help is appreciated.

```
$year = strip_tags(trim($_GET['year']));
$monthname = strip_tags(trim($_GET['monthname']));

$q = "select * from blog where year(date)='$year' and monthname(date) ='$monthname' order by date desc "; 
$result= mysql_query($q, $connection) or die 
("Could not execute query : $q." . mysql_error()); 

// dynamic navigation variables 
$rows_per_page=1; // adjust the number here to display number of entries per page 
$total_records=mysql_num_rows($result); 
$pages = ceil($total_records / $rows_per_page); 

$screen = $_GET["screen"]; 
if (!isset($screen)) 
$screen=0; 
$start = $screen * $rows_per_page; 
$q .= "LIMIT $start, $rows_per_page"; 
$result= mysql_query($q, $connection) or die 
("Could not execute query : $q." . mysql_error()); 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id=$row["id"]; 
    $name=$row["name"]; 
    $email=$row["email"]; 
    $entry=$row["entry"]; 
    $date=$row["date"]; 
    $icon=$row["icon"]; 
    $title=$row["title"]; 

?> 

    <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"> 
    <tr> 
    <td><?php echo "$title"; ?></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td> 
    <p><img src="<?php echo "$icon"; ?>" alt="icon" align="left"><?php echo "$entry"; ?></p> 
    <p>Posted by <a href="mailto:<?php echo "$email"; ?>"><?php echo "$name"; ?> on <?php echo "$date"; ?>.</p> 
    </td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 

    <div align="center"> 

<?php 
} #end of while 

// Display dynamic navigation here 

// create the dynamic links 
if ($screen > 0) { 
    $j = $screen - 1; 
    $url = "display.php?year=$year&monthname=$monthname&screen=$j"; 
    echo "<a href=\"$url\">Prev</a>"; 
} 

// page numbering links now 

for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) { 
    $url = "display.php?year=$year&monthname=$monthname&screen=" . $i; 
    $j = $i + 1; 
    echo " | <a href=\"$url\">$j</a> | "; 
} 

if ($screen < $pages-1) { 
    $j = $screen + 1; 
    $url = "display.php?year=$year&monthname=$monthname&screen=$j"; 
    echo "<a href=\"$url\">Next</a>"; 
} 

?> 

</div>
```

Comment: You only want a table row output inside the while loop. Move the `<table....` and `</table>` outside the loop

Comment: do people really write this much code at once with out testing as they go?

Comment: I removed the entire table code outside the loop and left `<?php echo "$title"; ?> <?php echo "$entry"; ?>`

Comment: You have tested if the mySQL query returns desired rows?

Comment: @Dagon I actually tested the code many times. I know it's not the dynamic navigation [below], but I felt I should just leave it there just in case others want to know if there are anything else that's causing the entries not to display.

Comment: just echo\dump each variable till you find the problem.

Comment: @fusion3k @Dagon I removed the `year(date)='$year' and monthname(date) ='$monthname'` and I'm left with `$q = "select * from blog order by date desc ";` All my entries shows up fine, but I want to just view entries dated on that month and year only. I believe it's just probably something to do with that part I removed that's causing my entries not to show up?

Comment: `echo $q;` take the query run it in phpmyadmin, or the command line

Comment: @Aelyn 1) Follow @Dagon sugggestion; 2) Use `MONTH()` instead of `MONTHNAME()`. `MONTH()` is numeric: numeric comparison are ever better than strings.

Comment: @Dagon I actually found out what my error was. The code I had displayed originally actually worked, there wasn't anything that needed to be altered. I just forgot to include the word **monthname** on my link and left it as `display.php?year=2015&month=November`

Comment: nothing a little debugging wouldent of found an hour ago

Comment: @fusion3k I left the `MONTHNAME()` as it is because MySQL returned an empty result set if I changed it to `MONTH()` I found what my error was and did not need to alter anything in my code. It was the link on the address bar that I overlooked.

Comment: @Dagon I did your suggestion too. It was a little mistake I overlooked.

Comment: @Aelyn Either wait for someone to answer the question, or answer it yourself, then click the outlined checkmark to 'solve' the question.  We don't put 'solved' in the title here.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the word `monthname` on my address bar and accidentally left it as `display.php?year=2015&month=November` No code needed to be altered.